# Как достать из картинки кусочек

Tags: java, bufferedimage

[image: Вот картинка]

Нужно из этой картинки достать танк. С помощью `BufferedImage`.

Comment: На этой картинке целая куча танков. Вам какой?

Comment: Любой. Нужен пример как это делать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BufferedImage src = ImageIO.read(new File("tanks.png"));
BufferedImage tank = src.getSubimage(0, 0, 16, 16);
ImageIO.write(tank, "png", new File("tank.png"));
```